# In android how to Resize and user crop image before uploading image as profile pic

Tags: android, performance

I am beginner in Android, I searched a lot for user cropping image before uploading the image like in whattsapp and also minimise the size of the image interms of bytes, but i am not getting any reliable answer to add in my app

Comment: use this library https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Comment: txz, its very useful

Comment: Happy to help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways to do it . first is to provide a cropper for it and second is you can resize bitmap and then send it to server . In second case user will not know which part of image (probably center) is cropped and uploaded as his/her profile picture . So i will recommend  the first one cause in that way user will know which part of image is going to truncate.
You must know that its hard to use in-build android crop app intent as it shows different behavior in different devices .So you must use third party Crop library for it of you can create your own cropper. Here are some useful Crop libraries that you can use. There are a bunch of libraries for it on github you can look for for them .

[CropImageView](https://github.com/joshdholtz/CropImageView)

[Crop](https://github.com/carousell/cropimageview/blob/master/CropImageView.java)

[Crop2](https://github.com/bornbeauty)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Crop extends AppCompatActivity {

 private Uri picUri;
 File f;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_crop);
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

 Button btn_camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
 btn_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

 try {

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "makegifimage.jpg");
picUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

 } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"couldnt open your      camera",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }
  }
  });

  }


  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
if (requestCode == 1) {

 CropImage();

} else if (requestCode == 2) {

 BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
 bitmapOptions);
    ImageView im_crop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im_crop);
    im_crop.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
}

}

private void CropImage() {
try {

Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
 cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
 cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
 cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
 cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 2);
 cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
 cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
 cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
 startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

 Toast.makeText(this, "Your device is not supportting the crop action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

}
}
}
```

and add the button and imageview to  your layout

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/im_crop"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

  <Button
     android:id="@+id/btn_camera"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Camera"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Comment: yaa I used this code but it does not work in all devices and it depends on apps present in user mobile, but i dont want my app to depend on other app

Comment: Then i think you need to use some custom crop mechanism..You can try the answer posted by ADM

Comment: yaa I m going through those links and txz